# Untrusted connection visiting https://www.opensource.apple.com/

Tags: tls, authentication, certificates, web-browser, firefox

Somebody on Stackoverflow posted some code from https://www.opensource.apple.com/

When I click this link in Firefox (36.0) it says "This Connection is Untrusted". But other people on that thread on Stackoverflow say they don't have a problem with the link.

But, apparently, some people, besides me, do have a problem with this link
[If even Apple cannot properly install certificate](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/64747/if-even-apple-cannot-properly-install-certificate)

When I check the certificate at https://www.digicert.com/help/?host=www.opensource.apple.com it says "Certificate does not match name www.opensource.apple.com"

Why do I get this warning when I visit https://www.opensource.apple.com/? Why do some people not get the warning? Is this something I should worry about or can I safely ignore this warning and move on?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like the certificate is only valid for [opensource.apple.com](https://opensource.apple.com), not [www.opensource.apple.com](https://www.opensource.apple.com):

> www.opensource.apple.com uses an invalid security certificate.
>
> The certificate is only valid for opensource.apple.com
>
> (Error code: ssl_error_bad_cert_domain)

You can simply use the former.

Comment: But then why don't other people get the warning when using www.opensource.apple.com? Is the link they post somehow getting converted from opensource.apple.com to www.opensource.apple.com?

Comment: I do not think that is the case. Maybe they ignored the warning by adding an exception, are using the http version, or using opensource.apple.com

Comment: @Zboson. I vaguely recall that Internet Explorer is lax about certificate checking where the only difference is the www.

Comment: @TRiG I just tested with IE11, and that's not the case.  Perhaps earlier versions of IE were more lax (but I'm unable to test that at the moment).

Comment: IE8 shows a certificate warning as well.

Comment: IE6 can't load it at all, so there's that.